# combining multiple Optional parameters into one object

Tags: spring

I have the following method definition

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Ad> search(@RequestParams Optional<...> p1, @RequestParam Optional<...> p2, ... another 10 optional params)
```

How can I combine all those object of my search method into one object containing all of them? Something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Ad> search(@... Wrapper)

class Wrapper {
  Optional<...> p1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using no annotation at all: `public List<Ad> search(Wrapper wrapper)` ?

Comment: No, I thought that it needs an annotation

Comment: It shouldn't. The documentation for [@RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) shows that you can simply declare "command/form objects to bind parameters to" as such; you may want to use `@ModelAttribute` only if you need to declare a specific model attribute name.